# CopyFieldMutation.java ERROR cannot get comparator 1

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I'm running DSE 4.5.1 on a 3-node cluster in AWS with RF=3. One of the nodes gets this error in the system.log. See (long) stack trace below. I would like to understand what the error means or implies. Is this a cause for concern? Lastly, how do I resolve the error?

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.8.39 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

`ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests:34142] 2015-05-12 14:15:33,029 CopyFieldMutation.java (line 166) Cannot get comparator 1 in org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type). This might due to a mismatch between the schema and the data read
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get comparator 1 in org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type). This might due to a mismatch between the schema and the data read
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType.getComparator(CompositeType.java:133)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.split(AbstractCompositeType.java:100)
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.CopyFieldMutation.buildKeyValueIterator(CopyFieldMutation.java:275)
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.CopyFieldMutation.addPrimaryKeyFieldsToMutation(CopyFieldMutation.java:260)
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.CopyFieldMutation.createMutation(CopyFieldMutation.java:110)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.triggers.SolrAugmentationTrigger.augment(SolrAugmentationTrigger.java:76)
        at org.apache.cassandra.triggers.TriggerExecutor.executeInternal(TriggerExecutor.java:190)
        at org.apache.cassandra.triggers.TriggerExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.java:94)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.mutateWithTriggers(StorageProxy.java:532)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.executeWithoutCondition(ModificationStatement.java:546)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.execute(ModificationStatement.java:530)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:158)
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.DseQueryHandler.statementExecution(DseQueryHandler.java:207)
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.DseQueryHandler.process(DseQueryHandler.java:86)
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.QueryMessage.execute(QueryMessage.java:119)
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Message.java:304)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelUpstreamEventRunnable.doRun(ChannelUpstreamEventRunnable.java:43)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelEventRunnable.run(ChannelEventRunnable.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index (1) must be less than size (1)
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkElementIndex(Preconditions.java:306)
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkElementIndex(Preconditions.java:285)
        at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableList.get(SingletonImmutableList.java:45)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType.getComparator(CompositeType.java:124)
        ... 23 more
 WARN [Native-Transport-Requests:34142] 2015-05-12 14:15:33,029 SolrAugmentationTrigger.java (line 107) Error generating additional mutations for Solr copy/dynamic fields. Update will be applied without them
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Cannot get comparator 1 in org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type). This might due to a mismatch between the schema and the data read
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.CopyFieldMutation.createMutation(CopyFieldMutation.java:167)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.triggers.SolrAugmentationTrigger.augment(SolrAugmentationTrigger.java:76)
        at org.apache.cassandra.triggers.TriggerExecutor.executeInternal(TriggerExecutor.java:190)
        at org.apache.cassandra.triggers.TriggerExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.java:94)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.mutateWithTriggers(StorageProxy.java:532)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.executeWithoutCondition(ModificationStatement.java:546)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.execute(ModificationStatement.java:530)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:158)
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.DseQueryHandler.statementExecution(DseQueryHandler.java:207)
        at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.DseQueryHandler.process(DseQueryHandler.java:86)
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.QueryMessage.execute(QueryMessage.java:119)
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Message.java:304)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelUpstreamEventRunnable.doRun(ChannelUpstreamEventRunnable.java:43)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelEventRunnable.run(ChannelEventRunnable.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: Would you be able to post your Solr schema.xml and CQL table schema here?

Comment: There are 12 keyspaces on the search nodes in the cluster. I don't see any way to figure out if the problem is limited to a single keyspace?

Comment: It looks like what's happening is that there's a mismatch between the Solr unique key and the CQL primary key (partition key + clustering keys). See if you can enable INFO level logging and browse around before and after the error. If that doesn't help, at least your search space is narrowed down to the 12 unique key/primary key mappings.

Comment: You may also be interested to know that stored copy fields will no longer be supported in DSE 4.7